# What are the answers to Mayor Pauline’s quiz?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

After defeating Bowser, you can find Mayor Pauline waiting for you in front of Town Hall in New Donk City. If you talk to her, she will have quiz questions to learn more about her.

These questions include things like “What is my most treasured possession?” and “What do I plan to eat for dinner tonight?”. They appear in a random order, making it difficult to memorize the answers.

What are the answers to Mayor Pauline’s quiz questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Question: How am I doing as mayor of this city?
Answer: Fantastic!

Question: What is my most treasured possession?
Answer: A hat.

Question:  What kind of music do I like?
Answer: Peppy music.

Question: What am I bad with?
Answer: Fixing machines.

Question: What do I just adore?
Answer: Cake.

Question: What do you think my hobby is?
Answer: Going on walks.

Question: Which of these things did I actually do a long time ago?<sup>1</sup>
Answer: Captured by ape.

Question: What do I plan to eat for dinner tonight?
Answer: Fried mushrooms.

<sub>[Credit to @Bing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/325069/130645) for the following:</sub>
Question: What do I do on my days off?
Answer: Practice singing.

Sources: [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTHsCW3pmOg) and [article](http://www.gosunoob.com/super-mario-odyssey/mayor-pauline-quiz-answers-power-moon-57/)

<sup>1</sup> I don't know if there is basis for the rest of these questions and whether answers are found in game or not (presumably not), but this one stems from Pauline being the girl captured by Donkey Kong in the original Donkey Kong.

Comment: All the answers can be found by listening to conversations or otherwise talking to the other residents of New Donk City.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that wasn't in the accepted answer:

Question: What do I do on my days off?
Answer: Practice singing.

Comment: This might work better as an edit to the existing answer

Comment: I think this is fine standalone and I've upvoted but also edited it into my answer so it's more complete

Answer (score 2):

There are 10 questions in total. Here is the last one that @Tas and @Bing have missed:

"What kingdom would I most like to visit right now?" Answer: Cloud Kingdom.

Also here is a video someone has recorded showing all Pauline's responses to all answer choices: